# Server works and I can connect locally, but friends cannot connect externally

Tags: azerothcore

I have followed the guide https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/installation to the letter and everything is working great, but friends cannot connect through my external IP though and I'm out of ideas.

I have:

- No firewall or AV in the way
- Forwarded ports 8085 and 3724
- Added my computer to the router's DMZ (Nuclear option when forwarding didn't seem to work)
- Changed the address field in the DB realmlist table to my external IP
- authserver and worldserver running and allowing local connections

An extra note is https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ says the ports are not open while I have the servers running as if they aren't listening on them.

Answer (score 1):

I probably don't have the solution for u but thought id share some thoughts

People can connect to my server but that website u linked at the end does also say that the ports are closed for me as well so I'm not sure how trustworthy it is

When I first made my server the DB realmlist change was the fix that worked for me but since u already seem to have done that I'm afraid Ive no idea

With that said. In Heidisql at least there were 2 places in realmlist u had to change the IP, in the Table:Realmlist and Data tabs

Comment: Yeah, Table:Realmlist is where you set data types and default values for when you insert a new entry. Nevertheless I tried changing the default value and well but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

I just learned that my modem from CenturyLink is also acting as ANOTHER router so fun stuff. Making it a transparent bridge is just a bag of cats I'm not gonna open so I guess I get to play WoW with myself for now.

Comment: I went ahead and bypassed the modem/router from centurylink, this works because its modem functionality isn't used for fiber optic thankfully (just had to set up the PPP credentials and vlan tagging in the router). Ports show as open and I can connect externally to my server now.